# Thinking sphinx not reindexing for delta=true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am facing problem in thinking sphinx

What i have following table structure

```
title => varchar
desc => varchar
is_deleted => boolean
```

Here is my denine_index

```
define_index do
      indexes title, :sortable => :insensitive
      has :is_deleted, :type=>:boolean
      where "is_deleted = false"
      set_property :delta => true
    end
```

Here when I **edit** the topic and **search** it with **edited name**, I get the topic and when I search it with **old name** I get the **same topic**. For eg if earlier topic had name **"Foo"** and I **renamed "Foo" to "Woo"**, on **searching "Woo"** I **get "Woo"**, but on **searching "Foo"**, I again **get "Woo"**. Moreover when I **set is_deleted => true** and **search "Woo"** I **don't get**  anything, but on **searching "Foo"** again I **get "Woo"**. I can't understand why it is happening? Does sphinx **don't delete** the **older** index on **creating newer index** for **delta=true**.

Again on rebuilding sphinx, i don't get such problems, and all delta is set to false as expected.

Comment: I would like you to observe rails logs whether or not indexes getting built. Also you can add debug statement such as logger.info object.inspect before and after the indexing happens i.e. object save b4 n after object save call.

Comment: are you having the field `delta` (boolean field) in your model?

Comment: no delta is working fine, but it is not re-indexing, as I told if I search using old topic name I can see new topic, even when it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use sphinx sql_query_killist to kill results from main index when you know it exists in your delta index similar to these: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-sql-query-killlist.html

Comment: Do we need different sphinx setup for this?